# I want to use TextButton properties like color to change using dynamic function

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the function I want to change in

---

The function is as below:

```
Expanded buildKey({Color bgColor, int n}) {

    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(bgColor),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(n);
        },
        child: Text(''),
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

And here I'm calling the above function

```
buildKey(Color: Colors.red, n: 1);
```

These 2 errors I'm receiving.

> error: The parameter 'n' can't have a value of 'null' because of its
> type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [xylophone] lib\main.dart:12)
>
> error: The parameter 'bgColor' can't have a value of 'null' because of
> its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> (missing_default_value_for_parameter at [xylophone] lib\main.dart:12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because youur passing parameters can be null, so give them property required as below.

```
Expanded buildKey({required Color bgColor, required int n}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(bgColor),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(n);
        },
        child: Text(''),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Expanded buildKey({Color bgColor, int n}) {

    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: bgColor != null ?  MaterialStateProperty.all(bgColor) :  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(n);
        },
        child: Text(''),
      ),
    );
  }
```